# Outputting list elements as Examples in Scala Specs2 when using forAll

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, specs2

In this code snippet, `SqlTypes.BinaryTypes` is a list of `(String, Int)` tuples.

```
"process binary types" >> {
  SqlTypes.BinaryTypes.foreach(sqlType => {
    val label = sqlType._1
    val value = sqlType._2

    s"$label" in new ABinaryColumnHandler {
      handler.canProcess(value) should beTrue
    }
  })

  "for all of them" in new ABinaryColumnHandler {
    handler should processTypes(SqlTypes.BinaryTypes)
  }
}
```

The first part, where the `foreach` is, creates a new Example for each element of the list, and runs the simple test. The second part calls a custom matcher:

```
def processTypes(typeList: List[(String, Int)]): Matcher[ColumnHandler] = (handler: ColumnHandler) => {
    forall(typeList) { sqlType =>
      val value = sqlType._2
      handler.canProcess(value) should beTrue
    }
}
```

The first part won't run without another example defined after it, because the return of that `foreach` is `Unit` and not `Example` or `Fragment`. I tried the second way because it seems much more straightforward, but I can't get its output to be structured the way I want, which is like this (in IntelliJ, but would look similar in SBT):

[image: output in intellij]

What I really want is for Specs2 to output the same in both cases, or be more like

```
process binary types
   for all of them
      BINARY
      VARBINARY
      LONGBINARY
```

How can I adjust how the latter example runs to output the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block using `>>` and returning `Unit` is ambiguous. Do you want to create examples or to create expectations?

```
// is it this?
"several examples" >> {
  Seq(1, 2).foreach { i => s"example $i" >> { 1 must_== 1 } }
}

// or that?
"several expectations" >> {
  Seq(1, 2).foreach { i => i must_== i }
}
```

In order to resolve the ambiguity you need to use one of those 2 methods:

- `examplesBlock` to create examples
- `Result.unit` to create expectations

Like this:

```
class TestSpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {

  "process binary types" >> examplesBlock {
     List("BINARY", "VARBINARY").foreach { label =>
      s"$label" in new ABinaryColumnHandler {
        Result.unit(Seq(1, 2).foreach(i => i must_== i))
      }
    }
  }

  trait ABinaryColumnHandler extends Scope
}
```

There is a note about those 2 methods in the [User Guide](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Methods).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm wanting to create examples. This is very close to what I was looking for. Ended up making a function that has an examplesBlock, and passing the types and the matcher into that function. E.g. `"process binary types" >> { eachTypeShould(SqlTypes.BinaryTypes, beTrue) }`